# Submit posts data from external website into laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I have a website that when the post is submitted goes to an external site where laravel is installed. I have a generic form on the website and upon submission i keep getting the 419 error in laravel. I've added the url in VerifyCsrfToken and it still wont work.

/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'https://pharaohmfg.com/collections/*'
    ];
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PostController@index')->name('home.index');
Route::post('callback', 'PostController@callback')->name('callback.post');
```

postController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller 
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect()->away('http://pharaohmfg.com');
    }

    public function callback(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->all();
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong? the website is https://pharaohmfg.com/collections/billiard-pool-tables/products/siamun-pool-table

Comment: Does your route has a name? I think you need to use the name for the `$except` property.

Comment: Also, the `$except` should be the route (endpoint) that is excluded.

Comment: i dont get what  your saying

Comment: Does your route has a name? Can you show me your `routes/web.php`?

Comment: @ChinLeung  updated the post

Comment: You should add `/callback` in the $except array

Comment: @SrinathReddyDudi That is an answer, and shouldn't be in comments.  It is also nearly the right answer, so you're likely missing out on a bunch of credit.

Comment: @J.A.Streich I am not sure if the community would accept such a short and simple one's as an answer. So i thought to leave it as a comment. Anyways thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out,

in app/http/kernel.php i commented out the verifycsrftoken class from being loaded.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: This would disable the verification for all your requests though.

Comment: i know, thats ok, i just need it for something simple

Comment: What I meant is this is not a real solution... It's just a way to bypass the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options that are better than your current self-answer.

### Fix Your `$except`

First, your `$except` should be the route the form posts to, not the url the form is on.  This has the benefit of having whatever else is in the Laravel app be protected by CSRF tokens.  Your current solution turns all of them off for everything.  This is not ideal, but it will accomplish what you are looking to do.

### iframe Your Form

Make the form an iframe so you can have a legit CSRF token in the first place.  This is what FaceBook and Twitter often do (or did the last time I look) for their social media buttons (like, share, retweet).

### Ajax

Setting up cors headers, you can write some fancy js to fetch the CSRF token from another route, while keeping the form on the external site.  The upside is that you could also submit the form using ajax making the existence of the external server obvious. This, like the iframe solution, would allow everything to be served with proper CSRF tokens.